# "Wi-Fi" doesn't have a valid IP configuration - Windows 8 - ASUS A55A

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

This error happens to us about once a week. We've not been able to solve the problem.

## Here is some further information:

1. The problem occurs on my computer but not my wife's computer.
2. Resetting the wireless router doesn't help.
3. Resetting the modem *might* help but we're not sure.
4. Restarting the computer does not help.

## Here are some of the error log details:

### Windows Network Diagnostics

#### Issues found

- "Wi-Fi" doesn't have a valid IP configuration Not fixed
- Investigate router or broadband modem issues Failed
- Reset the "Wi-Fi" adapter Completed

### Issues found

- "Wi-Fi" doesn't have a valid IP configuration Not fixed
- Investigate router or broadband modem issues Failed

If you're connected to a hotspot or domain network,contact the network 
administrator. Otherwise: 1. Unplug or turn off thedevice. 2. After all the lights 
on the device are off, wait at least 10 seconds. 3.Turn the device on or plug it 
back into the power outlet. To restart a router or modem that has a built-in 
battery, press and quickly release the Reset button.

- Reset the "Wi-Fi" adapter Completed

This can sometimes resolve an intermittent problem.

## ipconfig output

```
Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gv.shawcable.net
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fda1:5f4b:bfe1:0:1542:dc9d:xxxx:xxxx
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fda1:5f4b:bfe1:0:8944:6f82:xxxx:xxxx
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1542:dc9d:2791:xxxx%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.142
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.gv.shawcable.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : gv.shawcable.net

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:38e3:241d:xxxx:xxxx
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::38e3:241d:3f57:xxxx%16
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

That's it.

## Update - Attempted recommended netsh commands.

Comment: Open the command prompt and run the command `ipconfig`. Append the output to the question.

Comment: @spuder Is posting any of that output to a public forum going to compromise my computer's security?

Comment: I commend your security consciousness. Because you are behind NAT, the information wouldn't be useful to an attacker. It looks like your wireless is turned off at the moment.

Comment: @spuder Good to know we're secure. Should I re-run ipconfig and post again with Wireless turned on? Would that be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with windows networks can often times be fixed by resetting winsock.

Run the following form the command prompt

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
```

If that does not solve the issue, you can try a windows 8 [refresh](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2293-refresh-windows-8-a.html)

If the issue continues, download the latest network adapter drivers from the manufactures website an install them.

If after all of that, the issue still occurs, contact Lenovo support, or take the laptop to a computer repair shop for further diagnosing.

Answer (score 0):

Open `cmd.exe` as administrator and type:

```
netsh int ipv4 reset
```

no quotations, or alternatively you can enter all 3 commands the reset the pc.